# English to PigLatin c#

Tags: c#

Just had this Pig Latin problem as "homework". The conditions I have been given are:

1. For words that begin with consonant sounds, all letters before the initial vowel are placed at the end of the word sequence. Then, `ay` is added.
2. For words that begin with vowel sounds move the initial vowel(s) along with the first consonant or consonant cluster to the end of the word and add `ay`.
3. For words that have no consonant add `way`.

Tested with:

> Write a method that will convert an English sentence into Pig Latin

That turned into

> itewray away ethodmay atthay illway onvertcay anay ishenglay entencesay ointay igpay atinlay

It does what it should with one exception which is not in the rules but I thought about it and I have no idea how I can implement it. The method I created does exactly what the problem is asking but if I try to convert an all consonants word into piglatin it does not work. For example `grrrrr` into piglatin should be `grrrrray`.

---

```
public static string ToPigLatin(string sentencetext)
    {
        string vowels = "AEIOUaeiou";
        //string cons = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";
        List<string> newWords = new List<string>();           

        foreach (string word in sentencetext.Split(' '))
        {
            if (word.Length == 1)
            {
                newWords.Add(word + "way");
            }

            if (word.Length == 2 && vowels.Contains(word[0]))
            {
                newWords.Add(word + "ay");
            }

            if (word.Length == 2 && vowels.Contains(word[1]) && !vowels.Contains(word[0]))
            {
                newWords.Add(word.Substring(1) + word.Substring(0, 1) + "ay");
            }

            if (word.Length == 2 && !vowels.Contains(word[1]) && !vowels.Contains(word[0]))
            {
                newWords.Add(word + "ay");
            }                

            for (int i = 1; i < word.Length; i++)
            {
                if (vowels.Contains(word[i]) && (vowels.Contains(word[0])))
                {
                    newWords.Add(word.Substring(i) + word.Substring(0, i) + "ay");
                    break;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
            {
                if (vowels.Contains(word[i]) && !(vowels.Contains(word[0])) && word.Length > 2)
                {
                    newWords.Add(word.Substring(i) + word.Substring(0, i) + "ay");
                    break;
                }

            }
        }            
            return string.Join(" ", newWords);          

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
           //Console.WriteLine("Enter a sentence to convert to PigLatin:");
           // string sentencetext = Console.ReadLine();
            string pigLatin = ToPigLatin("Write a method that will convert an English sentence into Pig Latin");
            Console.WriteLine(pigLatin);

            Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: Can you sort out the [formatting](https://imgflip.com/i/24zi2h)?

Comment: Have you considered using an if else structure?  In the last else you could implement the exception for any word that does not match any of the rules.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Yes I have tried but it becomes a mess and gives all sorts of wrong outputs. The only way I could make it work is to separate the if statements.

Comment: Does this need to all be in one method? Breaking this up to call several smaller methods to handle the work would be good for a non-homework situation.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/udoqh These are the full requirements with an example sheet and it does say "a method" so I'm trying to obey the spec. @JamieF

Comment: Why did you write **"homework"**? If it is not homework, then what is it? If it is, then why put `"` around it?

Answer (score 2):

Give this a go:

```
public static string ToPigLatin(string sentencetext)
{
    string vowels = "AEIOUaeiou";
    string cons = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";

    Func<string, string> toPigLatin = word =>
    {
        word = word.ToLower();

        var result = word;

        Func<string, string, (string, string)> split = (w, l) =>
        {
            var prefix = new string(w.ToArray().TakeWhile(x => l.Contains(x)).ToArray());
            return (prefix, w.Substring(prefix.Length));
        };

        if (!word.Any(w => cons.Contains(w)))
        {
            result = word + "way";
        }
        else
        {
            var (s, e) = split(word, vowels);
            var (s2, e2) = split(e, cons);
            result = e2 + s + s2 + "ay";
        }
        return result;
    };

    return string.Join(" ", sentencetext.Split(' ').Select(x => toPigLatin(x)));
}
```

The code:

```
string pigLatin = ToPigLatin("Grrrr Write a method that will convert an English sentence into Pig Latin");
Console.WriteLine(pigLatin);
```

gives:

> grrrray itewray away ethodmay atthay illway onvertcay anay ishenglay entencesay ointay igpay atinlay